# Change a binded string property throught non java application thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

Im trying to bind a label to some property that is modified outside the java application Thread and it throws not an fx application thread. I read the javafx concurrency documentation but Im honestly having a hard time of understanding it or how to implement it in my situation.

```
public class testApplication extends Application {
    private final StringProperty someString = new SimpleStringProperty("inicial value");
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Label testLabel = new Label("");
        VBox testBox = new VBox(testLabel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(testBox);
        testLabel.textProperty().bind(someStringProperty());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setSomeString("new value");
            }
        });
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You are simply not allowed to modify a bound property outside the application thread because the internal code will then try to update the bound control on the same thread.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mipa Understood . So the thread that modifies the property would have to be a Task ?

Comment: You can just wrap the update action in a Platform.runLater call.

Comment: As Mipa said, outside the FX Thread you may use Platform.runLater. Also, since the property is bound, you have to first unbind it in order to change its value